# WSGEN error: compilation failed, errors should have been reported

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, jax-ws, wsgen

I use this command from CMD and I just receive this "compilation failed" error. Even if I use the verbose option. What could be wrong?

C:\work\test\WSDLGenerator\target\classes>wsgen -cp . US.ESB.WebService.General.General_GetProducts -wsdl -verbose -Xnocompile

error: compilation failed, errors should have been reported

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the same error when using wsdl generator called com.sun.tools.ws.WsGen from jaxws-ri package.
I don't know how much it will help you but:

1. wsgen executes javac internally and eats stdout so you will not be able to see why it failed.
2. code was working with Java 9 fine. I only saw this issue with Java 11. Remember, they removed bunch of j2ee components from core java so your classpath might be inadequate.
3. in my case I've put webservices*.jar from metro project that we used to process annotations into classpath of WsGen and generation succeeded.